# Backends which allow api calls from iOS Android and Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mbaas

What BAAS backends exists which allow the pushing of data from a website (Admin panel) and the pulling of data from iOS and Android clients (Users)?

Comment: Firebase is what you're looking for https://www.firebase.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally use [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) or [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/).
Also you can always create your own Back-End.